Prevent `lsp` + `company` from losing completion after dot + symbol
In many languages . is specially treated, so e.g. after typing a foo. a user expects a completion for methods available from foo.
That works with company as well, however after foo. triggered a completion, typing an additional letter (expecting for the list to get reduced), makes completion disappear completely. And it won't appear again till I type letters ≥ company-minimum-prefix-length.
Any way to prevent that from happening? Besides reducing company-minimum-prefix-length to 1, that is.
Steps to reproduce

Create /tmp/.emacs as follows:
(package-initialize)
(use-package company)
(use-package lsp)


Start emacs as emacs -Q -l /tmp/.emacs test.py

Execute M-x lsp

Type "".
A completion should appear

Type c to reduce completions to ones starting with that letter


Expected
Completions get reduced to ones starting with c, i.e. capitalize(), casefold(), etc.
Actual
The completions popup disappears.

So, I found the problem to be specific to lsp, because eglot works fine in this case.

Based on the findings, created a report to lsp.

It was an lsp-mode bug, fixed in the latest code by this merged pull request.
Commit e379ae5 "lsp-completion-at-point: looking back a few more chars for trigger-char"
